# Visual Studio 2015 CTP - Android ant.bat build error MSB3073

Tags: android, visual-studio, batch-file, ant, build

I'm having a problem building my APK in MSVC 2015.
Could the problem have something to do with the build pipeline?

Any ideas?

```
2>------ Build started: Project: NativeApp1.Packaging, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
2>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
2>  ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\
2>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre
2>  NDK_ROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\android-ndk-r10\
2>  9.0 was unexpected at this time.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\AndroidPackaging\Android.Common.targets(280,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\\bin\ant.bat" debug -Dout.final.file="G:\Projects\Android\NativeApp1\ARM\Debug\NativeApp1.Packaging.apk"" exited with code 255.
```

Comment: Grammar, adding error code in title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first the JAVA_HOME is wrong, you should put SDK path not JRE path
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03
JRE_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7

this link should help you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn872463%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Sorry for my bad english.